# NServiceBus issue, messages still in queue and handlers are not picking messages

Tags: c#, msmq, nservicebus

When hitting the endpoint the main method gets invoked but subsequent handlers do not pick messages from queue. The queue keeps building.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?
Thanks,

Comment: Which version of NSB and are you using unobtrusive mode?

Comment: How are you hosting NSB?

Comment: Operating System : Windows Server 2008

Comment: We are using Nservicebus as part of a .NET Solution. Do just deploying dll in IIS as part of project.

Answer (score 0):

So far we do not know much about neither your architecture nor your code, we have to guess here. So please bear with me if I say something that may not apply to your case.

Several things come to my mind:

**1.)** Did you see this tread? [NServiceBus Bus.Send().Register(callback) Not Working on IIS/Windows Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015090/nservicebus-bus-send-registercallback-not-working-on-iis-windows-server-2008)

**2.)** There is some unhandled exception or there is one that gets silently caught and causes your handler method to halt for some reason.

**3.)** Are you using WCF with NServiceBus? Last week my colleague implemented a WCF service that was hosted with NServiceBus and had a problem that sounds similar to yours. It hit the message handler for the first message, but never handled any subsequent message.

The reason was the handler never returned an enum value as a return code (represented as `YourEnum` in the code snippet), like it was defined in the service inheritance definition ([NServiceBus documentation](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/expose-an-endpoint-as-a-web-wcf-service)):

```
public class YourWcfService : WcfService<YourMessage, YourEnum> { }
```

The calling service did not need any return values, so my collegue did not return it (I cannot exactly tell why there where no compilation errors, it was not my code...). Therefore the handler method never finished correctly and no other messages could be handled.